# Is it possible to reach random youtube videos with creating random url's

Tags: python, url, youtube

I am trying to find random videos with creating random id's. According to my logic i create random video id for link and check its html. if a video is exist, there are multiple video id's like 15 or 20. if it is not a valid url there only 5 or 6 video id's in html.

```
import urllib.request
import re
import random
import string

def random_url():
    #There is random 11 digit after v=
    url_base = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="

    for _ in range(11):
        url_base += (random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits))

    #valid videos has at least 10 video id on the html. 
    #Thats how code i check it is valid video or not
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url_base)
    video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())
    
    if len(video_ids) < 10:
        print(url_base)
        return random_url()
    else:
        print(video_ids)
        print(url_base)
        print("done")


random_url()
```

when i tested, the detection works fine but i couldn't find any video before recursion limit come out. what should i do?

Comment: What do you expect `return random_url()` to do?

Comment: @matszwecja it is for repeating the process if program couldn't find a valid video url.

Comment: There are 62^11 possible combinations of ascii digits and letters in an 11-character string. If you could generate 100 million combinations per second, you'd still need around 100 years to go through them all. You will never find a video with this method.

Comment: [This random approach works in practice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&lc=UgwP_q99F1q8dAaWtfZ4AaABAg) cf [`0000088ZZQg`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0000088ZZQg) but does not in a reasonable time.

Comment: Apart from the vast number of possible IDs and the tiny probability that your generated ID will correspond to an actual video, YouTube may well throttle you if you're firing a rapid stream of invalid URLs at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is not the right approach here. You want to simply retry until you find something valid which might not happen for a LONG time.

Note that there is propaganda suggesting there are "a billion videos on YouTube". However, randomly guessing a URL even without the valid punctuation that some videos have gives you 52 billion combinations that are invalid for every single valid URL. Even just adding in the additional option of the `-` and you jump to 62 billion misses for every hit.

For additional context, 62 billion seconds is closing in on 2000 years. Good luck :-)

```py
import urllib.request
import re
import random
import string

def random_url():
    all_letters_and_numbers = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "-"
    url_base = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
    attempts = 0
    while True:
        attempts += 1
        url_actual = url_base + "".join(random.choices(all_letters_and_numbers, k=11))
        #url_actual = url_base + "dQw4w9WgXcQ"  ## uncomment for valid "Rick Roll"
        print(f"Attempt: {attempts} Trying: {url_actual}")
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(url_actual)
        video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())
        if len(video_ids) >= 10:
            return url_actual

print(f"Found: {random_url()}")
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by [Eduardo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16646078/eduardo-motta-de-moraes), it is unlikely for you to find a video before you hit the recursion limit.

Thus, recursion is not the right approach here.

A simple solution to this problem is to replace your recursion with a loop.
Make `random_url` return something (for instance, a boolean denoting whether it found a video) and you can loop until you find a video as such:

```py
while not random_url():
    pass
```

Of course, this is still not an efficient or elegant solution, but will at the very least not run into the limits of recursion.